# How do you properly extract data from a firestore query and use it in a react native component?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to receive some data from a firestore database by making a query. I wish to create an array of objects, containing the data of the documents that match our "isMale" criteria. The query works well, but when we try to create an array which contains the objects, the array becomes very (infinitely?) long. The array should have a length of two, but instead it repeats the same two entries again and again. I will show you the code to our problem below, and point out where the problem is:

First we have our imports. Here, fireDB is the name of the initialized firestore database.

```
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import React, { useState } from "react";

import fireDB from "../Configurations/firebase";

import {
  doc,
  getDoc,
  collection,
  where,
  getDocs,
  query,
} from "firebase/firestore";
```

Here is the component we want to export:

```
export default function TestingPage() {
  const [dbData, setDbData] = useState([]);
  const q = query(collection(fireDB, "userData"), where("isMale", "==", true));

  const getDataQuery = async (someQuery) => {
    const docArray = await getDocs(someQuery);
    return docArray;
  };
```

The below piece of code is where I personally believe the problem is. This is where we try to create an array of objects that should be two long.

```
  getDataQuery(q).then((fullfilledPromise) => {
    fullfilledPromise.forEach((doc) => {
      setDbData([...dbData, doc.data()]);
    });
  });

  console.log(dbData);
```

Finally, the return and rendering of the component itself:

```
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        flex: 1,
      }}
    >
      <Text></Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

By implementing the below code, we get the following output in the console, which is not what we want:

```
  Object {
    "isMale": true,
    "password": "testingPassword1",
    "userName": "Kristian13",
  },
]
Array [
  Object {
    "isMale": true,
    "password": "testingPassword1",
    "userName": "Kristian13",
  },
  Object {
    "isMale": true,
    "password": "testingPassword1",
    "userName": "Kristian13",
  },
  Object {
    "isMale": true,
    "password": "secondPassword",
    "userName": "David",
  },
  Object {
    "isMale": true,
    "password": "secondPassword",
    "userName": "David",
  },
  Object {
    "isMale": true,
    "password": "secondPassword",
    "userName": "David",
  },
  Object {
    "isMale": true,
    "password": "secondPassword",
    "userName": "David",
```

If we change the third piece of code for the following, we manage to only log the right number of objects to the console:

```
  getDataQuery(q).then((fullfilledPromise) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < fullfilledPromise.docs.length; i++) {
      console.log(fullfilledPromise.docs[i].data());
    }
  });
```

Gives:

```
Object {
  "isMale": true,
  "password": "testingPassword1",
  "userName": "Kristian13",      
}
Object {
  "isMale": true,
  "password": "secondPassword",
  "userName": "David",
}
```

The problem here is that this isn't an array that can be accessed later. If we try something like the following code, we get the same problem as above.

```
  getDataQuery(q).then((fullfilledPromise) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < fullfilledPromise.docs.length; i++) {
      setDbData([...dbData, fullfilledPromise.docs[i].data()]);
    }
  });

  console.log(dbData);
```

So, I hope my question is clear. How do I create the array dbData, which consists of two objects containing the information shown in the second to last code block?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, the problem lies in the 3rd block of code you provided. SetState is asynchronous, and for-each loops don't wait for asynchronous code to finish before moving on to the next iteration. There are two solutions you can use:

1. Use a callback within your for-each loop like this:

   ```
   getDataQuery(q).then((fullfilledPromise) => {
       fullfilledPromise.forEach((doc) => {
         setDbData(prev=>[...prev, doc.data()]);
       });
     });
   ```
2. Or you can just append all documents that match your criteria in a temporary array, then set your dbData state variable to this array once all data has been added, like so:

   ```
   getDataQuery(q).then((fullfilledPromise) => {
       let tempData = [];
       fullfilledPromise.forEach((doc) => {
          tempData.push(doc.data());
       });
       setDbData(tempData);
     });
   ```

How are you checking dbData's final value? I traditionally monitor state variable updates with a useEffect like so:

```
useEffect(()=>{console.log("DbData updated: " + 
dbData);}, [dbData]);
```

I'm not sure what else it could be, I ran your code samples on my side and they seemed to work. Maybe check the initial size of your fullfilledPromise collectionQuery to make sure it's not infinitely long?

Comment: Thank you for the response! Unfortunately, both of these solutions produce the same problem as in the original post. The array dbData still becomes infinitely long, instead of having a length of two.